# How to use onchange and onload together

Tags: javascript, html

I have function inside select
but i want to execute function when page shows up(load) and when value is changed. Actually is executed only when value is changed.

My code is here:

```js
function go(x) {
  var text = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.ppselect2');
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.value = text;
  });
};
```

```html
<select class="dntselect" onchange="go(this); return false;">`
```

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself, do you want to use them together or not?

Comment: Yes i want to use them together.

Comment: well the above works for when the items is changed. If you want the same "go()" function to run when the page loads, then create an onload event and call it from there, and pass in a valid element object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   // Create a new 'change' event
   let changeEvent = new Event('change');

   // Dispatch it.
   document.querySelector(".dntselect").dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
});
```

1. Listen for "load" event.
2. Select the given element.
3. Create a new "change" event and dispatch

Answer (score 0):

So execute it with the reference to the element.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    go(document.querySelector('.dntselect'))
});
```